# How to cancel celery chain from inside task (request.chain, request.callbacks are missing)

Tags: python, django, task, celery

First S/O question!
I know this has been partly covered in some other S/O threads but I haven't found a working solution based on related issues so far.

I have a celery chain i'm calling like so:

```
        result = chain(do_one_search.s(user_id) |
                       do_another_search.s() |
                       and_now_score.s() |
                       and_another_task.s() |
                       order_product.s()).apply_async(expires=10, retry=True)
```

Where each task is set up like so:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=3)
def do_one_search(self, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
    user.do_one_search_worker_id = current_task.request.id
    user.save()
    if user.passes_a_check:
        some_util = SomeUtil()
        result = some_util.search_util(user_id)

        if user.fails_a_check_after_util_runs:
            revoke(current_task.request.id, terminate=True) # this doesn't work
            self.request.chain = self.request.callbacks = None # this doesn't work
        else:
            return guid
    else:
        self.request.chain = self.request.callbacks = None # yup, doesn't work.
```

So `revoke` isn't working — the next task in the chain runs anyway.
Setting `self.request.chain/callbacks` to `None` is also not working. I can't access anything in the chain or callbacks on the `self.request` object -- they both return empty. I thought it might be a Celery version syntax issue and tried `self.request.chain[:] = []` and that throws an error (NoneType).

I have also raised an exception in the `fails_a_check_after_util_runs` block to make sure the task ID is accessible via `current_task` — it is.

I thought it might be that `results` are disabled but trying to get AsyncResult objects from these worker IDs works fine (they're always `PROCESSING`) which I *think* would not be the case if `results` was disabled.

I'm not a Celery expert so I'm pretty stumped here...any ideas from folks who know more than I? Am I missing something about `shared_task`s or `chain`s?
Thanks!!